# How to send id to other controller for create?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, entity

I trying to create table which shows list of items from other table with foreign key of current table and with the ability to create new row with id of current table.

I already tried to create RouteMap:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GroupsStudents",
    url: "{controller1}/{id}/{controller2}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller1 = "Groups", id = 
    UrlParameter.Optional, controller2 = "Students", action = 
    "Create" });
```

and in Students:

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id)
 {
    ViewBag.GruopID = new SelectList(db.Groups, "GroupID", "Name", 
    db.Groups.First(p => p.GroupID == id));
    return View();
 }
```

but i get this error: The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required.

There is my tables:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupID")]
    ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentD { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't have two controllers in a route. Just one. And `controller1` is not `controller`, nor is `controller2`. As the error message says, you need a `controller` route value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can define your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GroupsStudents",
    url: "Groups/{groupId}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Students", action = "Create" });

public ActionResult Create(int groupId)
 {
    ViewBag.GruopID = new SelectList(db.Groups, "GroupID", "Name", 
    db.Groups.First(p => p.GroupID == groupId));
    return View();
 }
```

Also, I believe groupId parameter should not be optional.